# However we cannot choose between the following variants of pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting an error when building a release version but a debug build works fine.

dependency name: implementation "com.plaid.link:sdk-core:3.2.6"

```
Error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
          - jvmApiElements-published
          - jvmRuntimeElements-published
          - releaseApiElements-published
          - releaseRuntimeElements-published
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'jvmRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
          - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'jsApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'jsRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'linuxX64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'macosX64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
   > Could not resolve pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.plaid.link:sdk-core:3.2.6
      > The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
          - jvmApiElements-published
          - jvmRuntimeElements-published
          - releaseApiElements-published
          - releaseRuntimeElements-published
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'jvmRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
          - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'jsApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'jsRuntimeElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'linuxX64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'macosX64ApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability pro.streem.pbandk:pbandk-runtime:0.10.0-beta.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component and the consumer needed an API of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Hey, can you post your Gradle files? I got this issue also as I placed a grade block within another block, which was the false one. In my case I place the `buildFeatures` in `buildTypes` but it needed to be in the `android` block

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

One of things that I'm aware of that can cause this problem is by having a Java library module referencing an Android library module. That's not a legitimate thing to do, but it causes a similar error as ir2id mentioned.

An Android Library may reference a Java Library module, but you need to specify the default configuration.  Here's how you add the Java library dependency to your Android library project:

use: implementation(project(":your-java-lib-project","default"))

don't use: implementation(project(":your-java-lib-project"))

or your build won't know whether to use the debug or release version.

I think ir2pid is having a similar problem but not with Java library projects but rather with Kotlin library projects.